# Use of Tikzpicture and Includegraphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

The following codes output only the line but the figures are disappeared. Could anybody suggest how to force both the drawn line and the figures in the output? Many thanks!

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{picture}(300,570)(0,80)
\begin{tikzpicture}
\put(0,440){\includegraphics[width=5.8in]{s1cbymax}}
\put(0,330){\includegraphics[width=5.8in]{s1f0bymax}}
\put(0,220){\includegraphics[width=5.8in]{s1f1bymax}}
\put(0,110){\includegraphics[width=5.8in]{s1f2bymax}}
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=5.8in]{s1f3bymax}}
\put(-10,360){\begin{sideways}\small$y^*$\end{sideways}}
\put(210,75){\small$\bar{u}/u_c$}

\put(210,75){\draw (30,0)--(30,5);}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{picture}
\caption[$Set\:1$: Velocity profile normalized by maximum velocity]{$Set\:1$: Velocity profile normalized by maximum velocity.}
\label{s1profilebymax}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Why do you use the `tikzpicture` environment here at all?

Answer (score 2):

The figures reappeared if you use the `tikzpicture`environment inside the `\put` command instead of directly nested in the `picture` environment:

```
\begin{picture}(300,570)(0,80)
\put(0,440){\includegraphics[width=5.8in]{s1cbymax}}
\put(0,330){\includegraphics[width=5.8in]{s1f0bymax}}
\put(0,220){\includegraphics[width=5.8in]{s1f1bymax}}
\put(0,110){\includegraphics[width=5.8in]{s1f2bymax}}
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=5.8in]{s1f3bymax}}
\put(-10,360){\begin{sideways}\small$y^*$\end{sideways}}
\put(210,75){\small$\bar{u}/u_c$}
\put(210,75){\begin{tikzpicture}\draw (30,0)--(30,5);\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{picture}
```

or simpler

```
\put(210,75){\tikz\draw (30,0)--(30,5);}
```

However, I would not mix TikZ and the picture environment. I would use just TikZ.

Comment: @pban92: did it help? If yes, it would be great if you would mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the checkmark at the left of the answer. Otherwise perhaps you could tell what's missing.